# Azure File Storage urls don't work the first time

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

**Background:**
I am moving a legacy app that was storing images and documents on local disk on the web server, over toward a PaaS Azure web app and using Azure File Storage to store and serve the files.

**Question:**

I have noticed that sometimes the url for file download fails the first time, either image links on a page are broken until I refresh or a download fails the first time, then succeeds the next. I am guessing that this is due to some issue with how Azure File Storage works and it hasn't started up or something. The only consistent thread I have observed is that this seems to happen once or twice in the morning when I am first working with it. I am guessing maybe my account has to ramp up or something, so its not ready on the first go round. I tried to come up with steps to reproduce, but I could not reproduce the symptom. If my hunch is correct, I will have to wait until tomorrow morning to try. I will post more detailed error information if/when I can.

```
    var fullRelativePath = $"{_fileShareName}/{_fileRoot}/{relativePath}".Replace("//","/");
    return $"{_fileStorageRootUrl}{fullRelativePath}{_fileStorageSharedAccessKey}";
```

Thanks!

Comment: I see that you're using Shared Access Signature. Does that SAS has an effective start date? If there's a start date and that value is current time, then the issue could be coming because of what is known as clock skewness (essentially there's a difference between the time on your machine and the time on Azure Storage).

Comment: I basically created one last month that works for several years, as we haven't figured out what we want those values set to.  &amp;se=2025-06-16T18:59:35Z&amp;st=2017-06- 16T10:59:35Z&amp;   Are you saying their clock may think my SAS start time hasn't occurred yet? I set it for back in June, so that should not be an issue. Thanks though! Any other thoughts?

Comment: Considering the start date is in June, I don't think that's an issue. When this error happens next time, can you please copy that URL and paste it in browser's address bar. You should be able to see a detailed error message. Please update your question with that error message. If possible, please also share the complete URL (you can obviously change the account name in the URL that you share).

Comment: Any update? Have you tried the suggestions provided by @GauravMantri? Please paste the URL in browser's address bar to get the detailed error message and post it on this thread for further discussion.

Comment: Having similar issue... my image url with SAS Signature works at times and at times when i refresh my webpage continuously.. i am getting a broken link.

Answer (score 0):

So its been a while but I remember I was able to resolve this, so I'll be writing this from memory.  To be able to access an image from file storage via a URL, you need to use a SAS token. I already had, which is why I was perplexed about this.  I'm not sure if this is the ideal solution, but what I wound up doing was just appending some random characters to the end of the url, after the SAS token, and that make it work.  My guess is this somehow made it unique, which may have helped it bypass some caching mechanism that was behaving erratically.

I'll see if I can dig up working example from my archive.  If so, I'll append it to this answer.